# What is difference between custom setting and custom object?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, customsetting

I familiar with custom object but what about custom setting?

Answer (score 8):

Custom settings is an standard object of the salesforce platform, where you can save your settings and associate it to the profile or user.

Here is some info from the official doc:

> Custom settings are similar to custom objects and enable application
>   developers to create custom sets of data, as well as create and
>   associate custom data for an organization, profile, or specific user.
>   All custom settings data is exposed in the application cache, which
>   enables efficient access without the cost of repeated queries to the
>   database. This data can then be used by formula fields, validation
>   rules, Apex, and the SOAP API.

Generally you can use custom settings for the parameter that can not be stored in the profile or user object. For example "Google Maps Key" for all profiles or whole org. Or region for the specific profile.

Learn more bout [Custom Setting here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm&language=en). 
Information about [how to access Custom setting](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en).

Comment: "This data can then be used by formula fields,validations rules.." But howz it

Comment: @Mani Take a look at the "Information about how to access Custom setting" link im my answer. You will find many useful examples over there, like `{!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}`

Answer (score 3):

A custom setting is very similar to a custom object, the main difference is that the custom setting is cached. It is especially useful to store information that will be often accessed from Apex code as it will perform better than a custom object as it doesn't have to be queried, it is also easier to manage it.

You can read more about it here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm